# Pros and cons accepting partial ownership of company as opposed to inheriting

Tags: mortgage, united-kingdom, small-business, home-ownership

My father owns property (buy to rent) and manages this through a small business in the UK. He probably has assets worth in the region of 750,000 GBP but is also still paying down the mortgages on each of the properties. He intends to pass this on to me and my brother one way or another and has suggested transferring partial ownership of the company to each of us. It sounds appealing to me, but I don't wish to proceed until I have a clear picture of the risks and benefits. To make things more complex, my parents recently emigrated, so it's not easy for us to sit down and go over the finer details.

What would be the pros and cons of us accepting this proposition, as opposed to simply inheriting the business? What additional information should I be gathering to make a decision?

Comment: What is your residency status and that of your father.

Comment: Both UK citizens, I live in the Netherlands and he lives in South Africa.

Comment: Are you domiciled in the UK?

Comment: Yes indeed I am